# Remove nodejs error dump

Tags: node.js

everytime I have a critical error which terminates the server on NodeJS which comes from a request of a client, he gets the error dump.

How can I change this behaviour ?

Comment: what error are you getting there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Express.js. Error stack trace is sent to client when environment is not `production` (please refer [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler)).

To disable this behavior, you should set `NODE_ENV` environmental variable
to `production`.

Comment: Exaclty what I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can process the error - more common is **404** and **500**.
Follow one example to do this (in case *express*):

```
exports.notFound = function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);
  res.render('not-found');
};

exports.serverError = function(error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  res.render('server-error', {error: error});
};
```

And create the files `not-found` and `server-error` (EJS or Jade for example) for show custom page in case of error.